# cURL SSL version 2 vs version 3

Tags: php, iis, curl, ssl

I have written a PHP script to transfer large files (100MB+) to another server using cURL. The process wasn't working until I set the CURLOPT_SSLVERSION to 3. Without setting that option, the process would transfer about 7MB, then die.

I would like to understand why that is case before I push this process out to all of our customers' machines. Is it server specific? Certificate specific? I just want to make sure that we won't have instances where some customers need the SSL version to be set to 2 for it to work.

If anyone can enlighten me on this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does php error log say?

Comment: There are no errors logged, and no exception thrown.